# Returning a whole range of cell contents in libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

In Microsoft Excel or google sheets I know it is possible to return the content of all cells in a range using the indirect formula. For instance, If I have in A1,A2,A3 cells 1,2,3 values respectively, an Indirect formula of such kind =Indirect("A1:A3") should be able to return starting from any given cell the value 1,2,3 consecutively. I cannot make it work with Libreoffice

[image: Google sheets example]

Comment: BTW in Excel you do not need the INDIRECT just `=B2:B10` will do it. Not sure about Google. And depending on your version you may need to array enter with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comment by Scott Craner, type `=B2:B10` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it an [Array Formula](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html).